# Sharepoint 2010 search not returning docx where search term is within HTML tags

Tags: 2010, search-results, html

I have a Word (Docx) document that contains an HTML table in the underlying XML. Within this table, there are several lines of text. When I upload this document into Sharepoint 2010 and search for any of the text within the HTML table, the document is not returned in the SP 2010 search results. If I search for any text outside of this HTML table, the document is returned with no issues. Is there a setting on the farm/site that I need to apply for the search to pick up text within the HTML table? I can't avoid my documents having this since they are generated from another system.